# GCC - error for different classes with the same name

Tags: c++, class, gcc, build, linker

Let's say I have two files:

a.cpp

```
class C { int x; };
```

b.cpp

```
class C { string s; };
```

I want to get an error about this during my build process. What should I do? (I don't mind using some external tool).

Comment: Curious as to *why* you want this to be an error.

Comment: See my comment to Alon's answer The main problem is corrupted vtables, the secondary problem is passing Cs between different compilation units which expect a different representation.

Comment: So are you going to refer global variables of type `C` declared in another compilation unit?

Comment: No, because I have a naming convention gcc plugin that enforces a naming convention that prevents it (:

Comment: Then what is your use case? Are you going to a pass a pointer to `C` to the function defined in another TU and thus referring to the wrong `C`?

Comment: @id256 - both `C`'s inherit from `A` and have virtual functions. I get vtable corruption. However, I'm also interested in a general solution if one exists.

Answer (score 1):

This falls under the fact that each c/cpp file is a compilation unit, separated from each, if you really want to verify this doesn't happen, you can objdump the *.o files generated by the compiler, parse them with some script, and see that non correlate.

Comment: I thought about this solution. It won't work for the case above, but it would work for the more dangerous case. The case above is relatively harmless as long different modules don't try to pass the object to each other and each one has a different class. A more dangerous case is when the object has virtual functions and then gcc produces a corrupt vtable for one of the classes. This case can be caught by searching for vtable symbols.

Comment: actually even if they don't pass it, but each defines it differently, you'd still get unexpected behavior(say unless inlined)

Comment: in terms of the C++ standard it is true, but I believe (maybe mistakenly) that gcc handles it ok.